# SVG transform affects other elements on page

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this very simple page: just a heading centered on the page and a couple svg buttons/icons below it. When you hover over the svg, they are transformed a bit larger. I noticed that when hover transformation is applied to the svg element, the header also moves a little bit. I think this is only Chrome related issue since I didn't notice the same with Edge (no kidding!). Is this something that can be fixed or should I just take this into account when designing the page? E.g. can't I put the header and svg elements inside the same container (there doesn't seem to be the unwanted movement when the header is not in the same container div)?

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#svg {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

.rect {
    fill: #000000;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.rect:hover {
    fill: hotpink;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #000000;
}


#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles - Copy.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <h1 id="header">Header</h1>

        <div id="svg">

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm using chrome and see no issue. What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: I think the problem happens during transition. If you switch it of it looks ok.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke my Chrome version is 63.0.3239.132

Comment: @Izabela Yes, I noticed that too. Plain scale transform works fine but transition causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that I centered the container div using transform: translate. If centering is done without transform: translate there is no unwanted movement in header. I tested this also in Edge and Firefox and it seems to work fine.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#svg {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

.rect {
    fill: #000000;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.rect:hover {
    fill: hotpink;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #000000;
}


#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}


#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles - Copy.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <h1 id="header">Header</h1>

        <div id="svg">

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see the issue also with Firefox, and it looks suspiciously like a bug.

Fixing it is relatively easy: reserve the space for the growing rects on the div, and align the SVGs to the center of the cross-axis:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#svg {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; /* centered */
    height: 55px; /* larger */
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

.rect {
    fill: #000000;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.rect:hover {
    fill: hotpink;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #000000;
}


#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles - Copy.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <h1 id="header">Header</h1>

        <div id="svg">

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

            <svg class="rect" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
                <rect width="50" height="50"></rect>
            </svg>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see the header still moving when I hover over svgs even though I changed the svg container height. Very strange.

Comment: On Firefox 57.0.4/Linux the Header is moving **up** in your version and stays inplace for mine, but on Chrome  63.0.3239.132/Linux your version is error-free (at least for some screen widths), but mine moves **down** during transition. Weird.